# Replace All unprediction combination HTML tag using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am fetching HTML from a webpage and trying to retreive data from it.

I have HTML like `<h3><strong>title</strong><h3>` that I want to replace with `<h2>`.
But, sometimes I find unexpected tags inside of the content, for example:
`<h3><br/><strong>title</strong></h3>`

How can i remove empty html tags like `<p><br></p>` and `<h3><br /><h3>` from a string?

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking

Answer (score 1):

You could always try using jsoup's .text() method on the element to grab the text only, and them putting that text inside an h3.

Answer (score 1):

To replace empty elements you can use the CSS selector `:empty`. Do so in a loop, since an element containing an empty element is not considered empty, but will be removed in the next iteration.

To replace `<h3><strong>...</strong><h3>` tags with `<h2><strong>...</strong><h2>` and remove other tags inside the `<h3>` tag, use `replaceWith`:

**Example Code**

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("url").get();

// clean up empty elements
while(!doc.select(":empty").isEmpty()){
    doc.select(":empty").remove();
}

//replace h3 with h2
doc.select("h3 > strong").forEach(strong -> {
    strong.parent().replaceWith(new Element(Tag.valueOf("h2"), "").html("<strong>" + strong.text() + "</strong>"));
});
```